# Explode String in PHP by regex

Tags: php, regex, php-7

I have input string as:

```
{"Google LLC.", "Microsoft technology, llc", "Samsung"}
```

I want to convert it to array such that:

```
array[0] = Google LLC.
array[1] = Microsoft technology, llc
array[2] = Samsung
```

How can I do this in PHP?

I tried to explode it by comma, but some strings itself contain commas.

Comment: You can use `preg_match_all` and the regex `"[^"]+"` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/Twt1pV/1/) and [here](https://rextester.com/CLP34717)

Comment: Why by regex if you have a json-object?

Comment: @Bernhard ^ it's not valid

Comment: @Bernhard this is not valid json.

Comment: OP can replace `{}` with `[]` and get a valid one.

Comment: @u_mulder Replacing {} by [] worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: oh yes, you are right

Comment: Let's just hope there is no items in the string with `{}`.

Comment: But there are some items which are not enclosed in quotes. What about them?

Comment: Consider sample string as : '"microsoft",ibm'

Comment: Just replace the curly braces with square brackets, then you can json_decode it

Answer (score 2):

You can remove braces at the start and at the end of a string and use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function to parse input

```
$str = '{"Google LLC.","Microsoft technology, llc",Samsung}';
print_r(str_getcsv(trim($str, '{}')));
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f919d745aa70109353259b5dfad6dd1b9ce5a3b0)

Comment: Good one. This is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an item in the string has `{}` replacing them will make the string incorrect.
What you can do to get around it is to substring out the first two and the last two characters the explode with `", "`.

```
$str = '{"Google LLC.", "Microsoft technology, llc", "Samsung"}';
$array = explode('", "', substr($str,2,-2));
```

Comment: But some substrings doesn't contain quotes